# PersistentActor cannot invoke persist handler in Future onComplete

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

I am pretty new using PersistentActor , 
when I try to call updateState from a future onComplete, fails , nothing happanes , tried to debug it and I do get to the persist call but not into the updateState

```
trait Event
case class Cmd(data: String)
case class Evt(data: String) extends Event

class BarActor extends PersistentActor{
  implicit val system = context.system
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
  def updateState(event: Evt): Unit ={
    println("Updating state")
    state = state.updated(event)  
    sender() ! state

  }
  def timeout(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) =
    akka.pattern.after(duration = 2 seconds, using = system.scheduler)(Future.failed(new TimeoutException("Got timed out!")))

  val receiveCommand: Receive = {
    case Cmd(data) =>

      def anotherFuture(i: Int)(implicit system: ActorSystem) = {
        val realF = Future {
          i % 2 match {
            case 0 =>
              Thread.sleep(100)
            case _ =>
              Thread.sleep(500)
          }
          i
        }
        Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(realF, timeout))
          .recover {
          case _ => -1
        }
      }
      val res = (1 to 10).map(anotherFuture(_))
      val list = Future.sequence(res)
      list.onComplete{
        case _ =>
          persist(Evt("testing"))(updateState)
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
  list.onComplete {
    case _ => self ! Evt("testing")
  }
```

And add this to receiveCommand

```
case evt: Evt =>
  persist(Evt("testing"))(updateStates)
```

Comment: thank @Pim , it is a workaround , which can work. in this case I would prefer to maintain the sender by using self forward Evt("testing") ,  but I am not looking for a workaround if I can avoid it

Comment: The root of your problem was calling persist in a Future instead of the receiveCommand method. You could also solve this by separating the processing and the persistence into different actors.

Comment: @igx In your case you cannot use 'forward' to maintain the sender since you're trying to persist after a Future completes ! Sender() is not guaranteed to be the same reference since the actor could have received other messages while waiting for the future to complete. Better to capture the sender() value in a 'val' and use 'self.tell(Evt(..), originalSender)'.

Comment: Does anybody know what is the source of this behaviour? persist in future issue. Even weirder thing is in debug mode it is working but in regular run nothing :/